# How to build a multi-select directory dialog in an eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, swt, multi-select

I've written an Eclipse plugin that uses DirectoryDialog to have the user select a folder to work with. I need to extend that dialog to allow the user to select multiple folders and loop over the selected folder paths in my code.
Now it seems DirectoryDialog honors the SWT.MULTI style and the user can select multiple folders - but when he hits OK, only one folder path is returned. DirectoryDialog unfortunately seems to lack an equivalent to FileDialog.getFileNames() and it's not subclassable, so I cannot add my own getDirectoryNames() function. FileDialog on the other hand does not let me select directories instead of files...

Any ideas on how to build a multi-select directory open dialog that allows me to obtain the paths of all selected directories?

Comment: See also the Eclipse [Bug 443250 - Support modern native directory dialog](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443250). This may be another limitation caused by the same anachronism.